# How do I calculate the number of "only child"-nodes in a binary tree?

Tags: java

NOTICE: this is homework-related, but I'm not tagging it as such because the 'homework' tag is marked as obselete (?)

Using the following class that implements a binary tree...

```
class TreeNode
{
  private Object value; 
  private TreeNode left, right;

   public TreeNode(Object initValue)
  { 
     value = initValue; 
     left = null; 
     right = null; 
  }

   public TreeNode(Object initValue, TreeNode initLeft, TreeNode initRight)
  { 
     value = initValue; 
     left = initLeft; 
     right = initRight; 
  }

   public Object getValue()
  { 
     return value; 
  }

   public TreeNode getLeft() 
  { 
     return left; 
  }

   public TreeNode getRight() 
  { 
     return right; 
  }

   public void setValue(Object theNewValue) 
  { 
     value = theNewValue; 
  }

   public void setLeft(TreeNode theNewLeft) 
  { 
     left = theNewLeft;
  }

   public void setRight(TreeNode theNewRight)
  { 
     right = theNewRight;
  }
```

}

I need to calculate the number of nodes in the binary tree that are "only children," this being defined as a node that doesn't have another node stemming from its parent.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static int countOnlys(TreeNode t)
  {
     if(t == null)
         return 0;
     if(isAnOnlyChild(t))
         return 1;
     return countOnlys(t.getLeft()) + countOnlys(t.getRight());
  }
```

I don't know how to implement the `boolean` method `isAnOnlyChild(TreeNode t)`

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Have you thought about implementing `hasOnlyOneChild()` instead?

Comment: I don't understand; could you explain more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are pretty close and have the traversal looking good but in your Treenode you do not have a link between a child and its parent. So You can not tell from say a left child if a sibling (right child) exists.

You could have a parent Treenode (along with left and right) so you could check how many children a given node's parent has. Or as ajp15243 suggested, instead use a method that checks how many children a given node has.

Some pseudo code of the latter:

```
//we still need to check if that only child has its own children
if hasOnlyChild(t) 
      return 1 + checkOnlys(left) + checkOnlys(right)
else 
      return checkOnlys(left) + checkOnlys(right)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! You, along with some other commenters, made me see that the current implementation of the binary tree does not allow nodes to detect the presence of sibling nodes (which is where I was running into trouble). I now see that it makes more sense to implement a `hasOnlyChild()` method instead.

Answer (score 2):

As you have already noticed, one solution is to count number of parents that have only one child. This should work:

```
public static int countOnlys(TreeNode t)
  {
     if(t == null || numberOfChildren(t)==0){
         return 0;
     }
     if(numberOfChildren(t)==1){
         return 1+ countOnlys(t.getLeft()) + countOnlys(t.getRight());
     }
         if(numberOfChildren(t)==2 ){
         return countOnlys(t.getLeft()) + countOnlys(t.getRight());
    }
         return 0;
  }

public static int numberOfChildren (TreeNode t){
    int count = 0;
    if(t.getLeft() != null ) count++;
    if(t.getRight() != null) count++;       
    return count;   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A parent has an only child if exactly one of the children is non-null (which implies that exactly one of its children is null):

`((t.getLeft() == null || t.getRight() == null)) && !(t.getLeft() == null && t.getRight() == null)`

You don't test, however, the node when you visit it as the recursive code traverses the tree. (This is similar to the Visitor pattern.) What you do is test for an only child when you are sitting on the parent. It's actually a logical exclusive-or test because one and only one of the children needs to be non-null to detect that this node has an only child.

So the algorithm is to

1. visit each node in the tree.
2. count it, if the node has only one child

That's it. The rest is plumbing.

Comment: I think I've confused people as to what exactly I'm testing for here...

I'm NOT testing each node to see if it's a leaf (i.e. it has no children); I'm testing each node to see if it has a brother/sister node (i.e. Node 1 has a parent node, Node 0, whose only child node is Node 1, therefore Node 1 is an only child)

Comment: so can it have children? so long as it doesnt have a sibling?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int onlyChild(TreeNode t){
    int res = 0;
    if( t != null){
        // ^ means XOR 
        if(t.getLeft() == null ^ t.getRight() == null){
            res = 1;
        }

        res += onlyChild(t.getLeft()) + onlyChild(t.getRight()));
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

whenever you traverse a binary tree, think recursively. this should work.

```
public static int countOnlys(TreeNode t)
  {
     if(t == null)
         return 0;
     if (t.getLeft()==null&&t.getRight()==null)
         return 1;

     return countOnlys(t.getLeft())+countOnlys(t.getRight());

  }
```

Comment: That's going to count leaf notes--nodes with no children. They might have a sibling.

Answer (score -1):

```
public int countNode(Node root) {

         if(root == null)
             return 0;

         if(root.leftChild == null && root.rightChild == null)
             return 0;
         if(root.leftChild == null || root.rightChild == null)
             return 1 + countNode(root.leftChild) + countNode(root.rightChild);
         else
             return countNode(root.leftChild) + countNode(root.rightChild);

     }
```